# Deleting files from server using PHP

Tags: php

My server stores 2 video files and 2 database records.

I am trying to delete it from my database if user chooses to delete the files.

Script to delete from database:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db_connection , "DELETE FROM `viewvideo` WHERE `video_id`='".$video_id."'");
$result2 = mysqli_query($db_connection , "DELETE FROM `video480p` WHERE `video_id`='".$video_id."'");
```

Using this script to retrieve the file path:

```
$deleteOrigVideo = mysqli_query($db_connection, "Select video_link FROM viewvideo WHERE `video_id`='".$video_id."'");
$delete480pVideo = mysqli_query($db_connection, "Select video_link FROM video480p WHERE `video_id`='".$video_id."'");
```

Delete Files:

```
unlink($deleteOrigVideo);
unlink($delete480pVideo);
```

The unlink part is not working. I am getting unlink() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path,

Original video is stored in **original** and 480p video is store in **original\480p**

`var_dump($deleteOrigVideo, $delete480pVideo);`

Output:

```
   object(mysqli_result)[2]
      public 'current_field' => null
      public 'field_count' => null
      public 'lengths' => null
      public 'num_rows' => null
      public 'type' => null
    object(mysqli_result)[3]
      public 'current_field' => null
      public 'field_count' => null
      public 'lengths' => null
      public 'num_rows' => null
      public 'type' => null
```

Comment: Can you show what `var_dump($deleteOrigVideo, $delete480pVideo);` returns?

Comment: Check the file permissions.

Comment: Also, you probably should be using prepared statements rather than injecting `$video_id` into the query, but, that's outside of the scope of this question ;)

Comment: You are only running a `query` that DOES NOT RETURN ANY DATA, it only returns a `mysqli_result` object. You need to do some sort of `mysqli_fetch_*()` to get the result set

Comment: @Will added output to my post.

Comment: Ok, thanks for posting that. It looks to me that your query isn't returning any results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$deleteOrigVideo and $delete480pVideo are not strings; They are MySQLi query result **objects**.

You'll want to do something like this (repeat for the second video):

```
if($deleteOrigVideo) {
    while ($videoEntry = $deleteOrigVideo->fetch_assoc()) {
        unlink($videoEntry['video_link']);
    }
}
```

I'm assuming the paths returned by "$videoEntry['video_link']" point where you want them to.

Comment: You don't need a while loop, his queries search for a specific ID.

Comment: I thought about that, but wondered if it might help people in the future. Valid point though.